# PIVOT SQL Data & Fill In Blanks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot

I'm attempting to transform this data:

```
ItemID  MonthAsInt  Month     Year  InvType     Quantity
4643    4           April     2011  Shipment    10
4643    5           May       2011  Shipment    10
4643    7           July      2011  Shipment    10
4643    8           August    2011  Destroy     10
4643    11          November  2011  Shipment    25
4643    12          December  2011  Picking     1
```

Into this (basically, a 12 month snap shot):

```
              February    March    April     May    June    July    August    ...

Shipment      0           0        10        10     0       10      0
Picking       0           0        0         0      0       0       0
Destroy       ...
```

I've messed with the `PIVIOT` method, but I haven't had much luck. At this point, all I have is the list of dates that I need between `GETDATE()` and `GETDATE() - 12 months` (retrieved with the query below):

```
DECLARE @BeginDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @BeginDate = GETDATE();
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE());

WITH CTE_DatesTable
AS
(
    SELECT @EndDate AS [Date]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
    FROM    CTE_DatesTable
    WHERE   DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= @BeginDate
)

SELECT DISTINCT DATENAME(MONTH, [date]) + ' ' 
        + CAST(YEAR([date]) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS MonthYear,
                YEAR([date]) AS YearAsInt,
                MONTH([Date]) AS MonthAsInt
FROM            CTE_DatesTable
ORDER BY        YEAR([date]), MONTH([Date])
OPTION          (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

See the query in action [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61425/cte-datestable).

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible? Am I going in the right direction? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @subt13, **Me**. I've never used it and I can't quite figure out how to "fill in the blanks". For example I need to show zero for all months that aren't included in the first result set.

Comment: Use pivot, that's what it is for.  You can handle null values using isnull(..., 0)

Comment: @subt13, if I could have figured it out myself after a couple of hours, I wouldn't have posted on SO.

Comment: No problem.  Please see my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without pivot (the syntax for which I find daunting as well). Since you don't know the actual layout of columns beforehand, I think this is easiest with dynamic SQL. Given the following table/sample data:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.foo
(
    ItemID INT, 
    MonthAsInt INT, 
    [Month] VARCHAR(12), 
    [Year] INT, 
    InvType VARCHAR(12), 
    Quantity INT
);

INSERT dbo.foo SELECT 4643,4 ,'April   ',2011,'Shipment',10
UNION ALL SELECT 4643,5 ,'May     ',2011,'Shipment',10
UNION ALL SELECT 4643,7 ,'July    ',2011,'Shipment',10
UNION ALL SELECT 4643,8 ,'August  ',2011,'Destroy ',10
UNION ALL SELECT 4643,11,'November',2011,'Shipment',25
UNION ALL SELECT 4643,12,'December',2011,'Picking ',1;
```

You can generate a list of months using a much simpler CTE, and build a dynamic SQL statement based off of that:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

;WITH n AS 
(
    SELECT TOP (12) d = DATEADD
    (
        MONTH, 
        -(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1), 
        GETDATE()
    )
    FROM sys.objects
    ORDER BY d DESC
)
SELECT @sql = @sql + N',' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + DATENAME(MONTH, d) 
    + ' = SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, d))
    + ' AND MonthAsInt = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, d)) 
    + ' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END)'
FROM n
ORDER BY d;

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT InvType' + @sql + '
    FROM dbo.foo
    GROUP BY InvType';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

I put the `PRINT` there so you could test it out before running it. I wasn't sure if you needed 12 months or 13 months, you can just change the `TOP (12)` to `TOP (13)` if you want 13 months, or remove the `-1` if you don't want the current month included.

Comment: You could probably build a `PIVOT` with dynamic SQL in a similar way. Also you may consider adding the year to the column name just so that the result is unambiguous. And finally, the output SQL does not have an `ORDER BY` - did you mean to `ORDER BY InvType DESC` or do you not care about order?

Comment: Works perfectly. I've never used dynamic SQL before. This is a perfect example of why I need to look into it a bit more. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you need a dynamic pivot: [see here](http://sqlwithmanoj.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/dynamic-pivot/)

**otherwise**

This is how you do it will pivot.  Of course, `PIVOT` requires you to know what your data will look like beforehand.  If you need a dynamic pivot, then there are plenty of dynamic crosstab/pivot queries/sps that people have already written.

```
DECLARE @BeginDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @BeginDate = GETDATE();
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE());

WITH CTE_DatesTable
AS
(
    SELECT @EndDate AS [Date]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
    FROM    CTE_DatesTable
    WHERE   DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= @BeginDate
)

    SELECT DISTINCT DATENAME(MONTH, [date]) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR([date]) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS MonthYear,
                    YEAR([date]) AS YearAsInt,
                    MONTH([Date]) AS MonthAsInt,
                    case when month([date]) < 5 then 'Shipment' else 'Picking' end InvType,
                    floor(10 * RAND() * month([date])) Quantity
    into #orig
    FROM            CTE_DatesTable
    ORDER BY        YEAR([date]), MONTH([Date])
    OPTION          (MAXRECURSION 0)

update #orig 
set Quantity = null
where MonthYear = 'February 2011'

select * from #orig

select *
from
(
    select isnull(Quantity, 0) Quantity, MonthYear from #orig
) SourceTbl
PIVOT
(
    sum(Quantity)
    for MonthYear in ([February 2011], [March 2011])
) PivotTbl

drop table #orig
```

Result:

```
February 2011   March 2011
0                   29
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `case when month([date]) < 5`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - to add sample data.

Comment: Ok, I gotcha. Hopefully the OP understands that's not part of the solution. Now, what about the other 10-11 months? :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I have faith in the OP's abilities :).  I didn't feel like typing it all out.

Comment: Sure, the other months should be a no-brainer. But mixing sample data in as part of the answer was very confusing to me. Feel free to borrow my tables for sample data, I think that decouples the question from the answer much better. Also, it seems like your solution will have to hard-code the `PIVOT` section... how will that look in March or April?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Yep, PIVOT requires hardcoded names.  That's just the way PIVOT works (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I understand how `PIVOT` works. I just don't understand how this answer will help the OP next month - he'll have to re-write it every month.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - He can either remove the year portion from the column header, or he can use a dynamic pivot and concat the two together.  I have updated my answer that links to a dynamic pivot example.

Comment: He can't remove the year portion from the column header. If he has February of last year and February of this year, that's going to confuse `PIVOT`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - yep, he'd have to filter on year and limit his query to be per year, otherwise it would be aggregating all years for each month.